# SQL Get all parent and child of active parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

Here is my case I have a table structure like :

[image]

I just want to get all active parents (i.e record with name A,E and G) and their child.

The expected result should look like this :

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Show the results you want.  A DB/SQL Fiddle would also help.  Images of data values are not helpful.

Comment: SQL is a language -- standardized but mostly celebrated by implementing deviations from the standard.  You need to specify the specific database engine you are using.  "SQL" is not a database.

Comment: Agree tag updated  @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with recursive as (
SELECT      par.Id, 
            par.Name, 
            par.ParentID, 
            par.IsDeleted  
FROM        table1 par 
JOIN  table1 chi 
  ON        par.Id = chi.ParentId  

union all 

SELECT      par.Id, 
            par.Name, 
            par.ParentID, 
            rec.IsDeleted  
FROM        table1 par 
JOIN  recursive rec 
  ON        rec.Id = par.ParentId  
),

check_tbl as (
       select Id,
       sum(IsDeleted) as IsDeleted
from recursive
group by Id
having sum(IsDeleted)=0
)

select table1.id, Name, ParentID, table1.IsDeleted
from check_tbl join table1 on table1.Id=check_tbl.Id
;
```

Comment: this will remove all record that have parent id as null (top level), also showing records who's grand parent is not active

Comment: I've made a recursive query. It must be suitable for this case